# Ubuntu 14: Apache Subversion Upgrade - Can't find version of SVN being used to serve the repo list

Tags: svn, ubuntu-14.04

I've been trying to upgrade an SVN server from version 1.8.8 to version 1.14.0. See the bottom of this description for the process that I've followed specifically. After executing that process, I've gone through and made sure to overwrite the binaries with the new ones provided in the installation, per the Release Notes on Apache Subversion's website.

When I go to the SVN webpage on a client, I still see the version 1.8.8:
[Collection of Repositories, Powered by Apache Subversion 1.8.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv9cg.png)

I've checked the version of all the CLI clients: (svn --version comes back with 1.14, svnserve --version comes back with 1.14, etc.)

Clearly, there's a disconnect here regarding the way that I thought this works, and the way that it actually works. I cannot for the life of me figure out where the "1.8.8" version is coming from, or how to fix it.

The main problem occurs when I need to create a new repository, I will write "svnadmin create /repo/path repo_name" and I get a this when I browse to the new repo: [Could not open the requested SVN filesystem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t777i.png). I am currently able to get around this problem by doing svnadmin create /repo/path --compatible-version 1.8, but, this really seems like an unnecessary workaround.

Does anyone have any idea where Apache is getting version 1.8 from? And, as a bonus question, do you have any clues on how I can get this upgraded to the same version as the toolset?

Steps followed to install newest version of Subversion and tools:

```
sudo rm -f /usr/local/lib/libsvn*
sudo rm -f /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsvn*
sudo rm -f /usr/lib/libsvn*

sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install scons

sudo apt-get install autoconf
sudo apt-get install libtool

sudo apt-get upgrade apache2
sudo apt-get install apache2-dev

wget https://mirrors.sonic.net/apache/subversion/subversion-1.14.0.tar.gz
./get-deps.sh

cd apr
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install

cd apr-util
./configure --prefix=/usr --with-apr=/usr
make
sudo make install

cd zlib
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install

cd serf
// Here, I fixed test/test_buckets.c line 1237, which uses // instead of /**/
scons OPENSSL=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu PREFIX=/usr
scons check
sudo scons install

cd ../
wget https://www.sqlite.org/2015/sqlite-amalgamation-3081101.zip
unzip sqlite-amalgamation-3081101.zip
mv sqlite-amalgamation-3081101 sqlite-amalgamation
./configure --with-serf=/usr --with-lz4=internal --with-utf8proc=internal
make
make check
sudo make install
sudo make install-tools

<manually replaced all binaries with new ones, since they installed in a different location>

sudo reboot
```

At this point, wondering if this is related to the mod_dav_svn plugin

Comment: How are you actually launching the `svn` server? If you had it installed in `/usr/local` I bet you also have a custom launch script for it.

Comment: I could be wrong, but, I think that the SVN repository itself is just a part of the file system, and an apache2 web server is configured to point to the file system and interpret the data so that it's browse-able on the web interface. Apache2 is a service that is started when the server powers up, through a script in init.d. The start part of the script executes the following: "apache2ctl start", where apache2ctl is a binary in /usr/sbin.

I'm investigating now as to how apache2ctl is configured

Comment: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/svnserver.html suggests `make install-svn`. I believe you need the local server component even if you use Apache for remote access but it's been a long time...

Comment: That's definitely a step that I didn't go through before. This entire process has been exactly like this - Oh look, another step that I missed that wasn't included in the INSTALL doc... Thanks a ton, I'll give that a try and give an update

Comment: Hmm, yeah, that's not exactly what I'm looking for. The instructions in the link above use svnserve while I'm using apache httpd

Comment: But the assumption that repos are just files in the file system is definitely not true for Subversion, as you can easily see byeinpecting a repo. (Many other systems have a more transparent approach, where you can indeed browse a repo with anything which can open files.)

Comment: I agree - I oversimplified. An SVN repo itself include a DB file, the hooks dir, conf dir, etc.. and, of course, it's not going to reflect the files that you check out on a client. There is the "middle" bit, which interprets these files. This will either be svnserve, and/or Apache, which uses mod_dav/mod_dav_svn. I think is where my problem is. When I create a new project using the latest SVN tools (1.14), I've got Apache unable to display the web page. I believe now that it's probably mod_dav_svn that is somehow built to only interpret SVN versions 1.8.8 and earlier

Comment: Sounds like you should also update the Apache bindings, yes.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to remake subversion again, and include the right CLI args in "./configure" to ensure mod_dav_svn.so is included in the installation, which I think is " --with-apache-libexecdir=/usr/lib/apache2/modules". Thanks for talking through this with me, let's hope it works this time around

Answer (score 0):

./configure --with-lz4=internal --with-utf8proc=internal **--with-apache-libexecdir=/usr/lib/apache2/modules** --bindir=/usr/bin --libdir=/usr/lib **--with-apxs=/usr/bin/apxs** --with-serf=/usr

When building subversion, I modified the configure line as above to get the mod_dav_svn.so to be generated